# Find the largest product formable using 3 elements in a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have attempted the problem and wrote the code. Could anyone tell me if my code covers all cases and if there is a better way to this this.

Here is my code

```
a = [-12, -4, 6, 3]
a.sort()


if a[0]*a[1] > a[-1]*a[-2]:
    res = a[0]*a[1]*a[-1]
else:
    res = a[-1]*a[-2]*a[-3]

print(res)
```

Comment: what if the array is full of negatives ?

Comment: here's an example of a list for which you get a wrong result: `a = [-12, -4, 13, 5, 0]`

Comment: This is a maximum product subset problem. By the way, how do you count duplicates in the input?

Answer (score 2):

This can be very efficiently done in O(nlogn) time and O(1) space. First, sort the list. Then return the maximum of product of last three elements of the list and product of first two elements and last element.

```
def prod (lis):
  lis.sort()
  return max(lis[0] * lis[1] * lis[-1], lis[-1] * lis[-2] * lis[-3])
```

Answer (score 1):

The most pythonic why would prob be to use itertools.combinations() and then apply itertools.starmap() so you could handle lists of different lengths or getting the product of a different number of elements.

Peep these docs :) https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're looking for, but if you're looking for the maximal product of 3 numbers in a list you could do something like that:

```
from itertools import combinations
from operator import mul

def find_max_3_product(a):
    return max([reduce(mul,x) for x in combinations(a,3)])
```

And, you can even generalize this to work for any `n`:

```
def find_max_n_product(a, n):
    return max([reduce(mul,x) for x in combinations(a,n)])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work always (assuming the input is already sorted):

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

def max_product_of_three( a ) :
    #a.sort()    # enable if needed
    if len(a) > 6 :
        a = a[:3] + a[-3:]
    products = [(np.prod(i), i) for i in combinations( a, 3 )]
    return max( products )
```

returns:

```
>>> max_product_of_three( [-12, -4, 13, 5, 0] )
(624, (-12, -4, 13))
>>>
```

There are only 20 possible combinations for the array of 6, so it works in the constant time with any array size (not counting the sorting, that will take O(NlogN))

Comment: any reason why you need a max of 6 elements to find the product and not 5?

Answer (score -1):

your approach is assuming that if the product of the first 2 elements from the sorted list is lower than the product of the last 2 elements then you just use the product of the last 3 elements but this is not always true since the product of the last 3 elements can be 0 or negative (ex: [-10, -9, -1, 0,  11, 20] or [-10, -9, -1, 11, 20])

you can use (assuming that `a` it is sorted):

```
res = max(a[0] * a[1] * a[-1], a[-1] * a[-2] * a[-3])
```

Comment: in the line `res = max(a[0] * a[1] * a[-1], a[-1] * a[-1], a[-3])` the part `a[-1] * a[-1]` seems wrong

Comment: in the same line, what's the point of comparing `a[-1] * a[-2]` and `a[-3]` ??

Comment: the condition `if a[1] < 0` has no `else`, hence no result is produced, the code is broken.

Comment: a[-1] * a[-2] * a[-3] is for the case when you have a[0] * a[1] < a[-1] * a[-2] , here is an example [-12, -4, 13, 5, 0]

Comment: have you ever tested your code??? `find_prod_3( [-4, -3, 5, 6, 7] )` results in `84`, while the correct answer is `210`

Comment: well should be max(a[0] * a[1] * a[-1], a[-1] * a[-2] * a[-3]), the function works well now

Comment: @lenik for simplicity I just use only the max line